# Internet Explorer currently state test

Tags: css, internet-explorer, testing, behat

I saw similar problems to my problem, but I have not seen useful solutions for my issue.
Situation:
When I play a video file within firefox, I can see current state of html-markup (F12) because of that I can trigger some funtions in my php behat/mink code.

The same situation occurs in IE, and I dont see current state of my markup-code and I can´t trigger my test-functions.

Example:
Firefox opens modal dialog and it appears by markup (F12) css class "open window"
IE opens modal dialog and it not appears by markup (F12) css clas "open window"

How can I detect current markup state in IE, when I can look only at markup?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code. I just looking for one css-selector, but it does not working
on IE10

```
$node = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $css_selector);
```

Problem beginns by IE10:

1. When i press F12 within IE10, i will see developertools.
2. I see within "HTML-section" current state of html-markup.
3. I click on icon and modal dialog appears.
4. Actually my html-markup changes after that. Some css classes come additionaly to video-tag.
5. I have to click by developertools on "refresh"-Button or F5 to see
   currently markup-state, which contains modal-dialog.
6. To achieve same effekt whithin behat, i use:

   $this->getSession()->reload();
7. That does not work. Behat can not find new css classes, which referes on modal-dialog.

Please look on picture:

[image]

I hope, it is clear now, what i mean :)

Comment: Modern versions of IE also have an inspector, hit F12 just like the other browsers.

Comment: How are you using this in your behat method?

Comment: In my behat i simply look for xpath-selector, which works by firefox and chrome.
I´ve just detected, that IE11 displays immediatly by "DOM Eplorer" (F12) changes, when i click on my video-tag:

From
`<body class="myClient" `
will be after click on video tag:
`<body class="myClient modal-open "`
After that, i retrieve "modal-open" in my behat-function.

BUT 
When i try this whin IE10 or IE9 
`<body class="myClient" ` will still displayed, although i´ve clicked on video-tag. Effekt is, that i can´t run my behat-functions.
How could i handle this behaivor on IE10 or IE9 ?

Comment: I don't really understand what happens and what you are trying to do. If you need to check the modal is open you could also check the selector for the modal is visible.Please provide some code (html source code of the section and behat step).

Comment: please, look above

Comment: An an alternative to reload you could try to get the current url and visit that url. If the modal is opened but the classes are not added you could get the  selector for the modal and check if that element is visible.

Comment: Thx. On the description, which i´ve updated, i´ve said, that:
`$this->getSession()->reload();` reloads just a page and my modal-dialog will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, for IE the class that you are using in the validation is not added and you are not able to check that the modal is opened.

As an alternative you could use alternative methods to verify that the modal is opened and to avoid cross-browser issues like this.

I think is better to work with what you already have without reloading or doing any actions that could lead to extra code that could affect other browser or could affect the stability of the scenario.

One way of doing this is to check that the modal is visible using isVisible() method.